# How to fix the 'Cannot GET/' error with BrowseSync?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm working with a Gulp setting, that will watch my HTML, Sass and files. How to solve the error below ?

> Cannot GET/

This is my code:

```
//Watch Files
htmlWatchFiles = './src/html/main/*.html';

//Input files
//  File for gulp-sass compiler
var inputScssFile = './src/stylesheets/**/*.scss'

function sassCompiler() {
    return gulp.src(inputScssFile)
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(autoPrefixer())
      .pipe(dest('./src/stylesheets/output'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

Here is my function to watch:

```
function toBrowseSync(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "src/",
            index:"./src/html/main/index/html"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch(inputScssFile,sassCompiler);
    gulp.watch(htmlWatchFiles).on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.default = series(sassCompiler,toBrowseSync);
```

Comment: @StephenS good job)

Comment: @StephenS, now Could you help with solution?

Comment: Did you tried this? Looks same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686538/gulp-browser-says-cannot-get

Answer (score 1):

For the BrowserSync configuration, the path used in the index property should be relative to the baseDir used. The documentation [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-server) also mentions this in a code comment.

```
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "src/",
        index:"html/main/index.html"
    }
});
```